# Place Order on Whatsapp at product category page Magneto 2

Tags: magento2

I have created Order on WhatsApp button using the following code and my code is working. I can show Order on WhatsApp button at product category page so please tell me how to show WhatsApp button at category page below side of add to cart button

code place at `app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<?php if($_product->getWhatsapp_order()){ //yes or no button?>
<button type="button"
        title="<?php echo $_product->getWhatapp_button_name() ;?>"
        class="action primary"
        onclick=" window.open('https://wa.me/0000000000?text=I want to order this product *<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>* Price <?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?> Link <?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ;?>/ ')"><span><span><i class="icon-whatapp"></i><?php echo $_product->getWhatapp_button_name() ;?></span></span></button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to override list.phtml file at location

> app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

And **Edit list.phtml file**

```
       <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
           ...
           ...
           <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
             ...
             ...    

            /* Place your WhatsApp button code here */                                  

        <?php if($_product->getWhatsapp_order()): //yes or no button?>

             <button type="button"  title="<?php echo $_product- 
                >getWhatapp_button_name() ;?>" class="action primary"
             onclick=" window.open('https://wa.me/0000000000?text=I want to order this product *<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>* Price <?php echo $_product->getPrice() ?> Link <?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ;?>/ ')"><span><span><i class="icon-whatapp"></i><?php echo $_product->getWhatapp_button_name() ;?></span></span></button> 

        <?php endif;?>

        ...
        ...


          <?php else: ?>


       <?php endforeach; ?>
```